# how to have object continuously follow users finger coordinates? not draging object. object following finger

Tags: java, android, touch, coordinates, sprite

I have tried to use different methods but to no avail. So I come looking for a fresh point of view.

I want to have a sprite follow the touch coordinates of the user. So if they dragged their finger across the screen the sprite would move or tween towards the touch coordinates but continuously update to 'follow' the users finger. If the user stopped moving their finger, the sprite would eventually come to a stop at the final touch coordinates.

I can get the sprite to move and tween to a single set of coordinates but not continuously update to follow along. This is for an android game. its in java. this is one of the basic functions i need to use so im not too far along. that being said I can accept direction for open gl or for canvas.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every frame, do

```
 Pos = (Pos * 0.95) + (LastTouch * 0.05);
```

Adjust the ratios until it feels right. Just make sure they add up to 1.

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly. im going to try this. Ill post a progress report tomorrow as it is 2 am here.

Comment: this works. i broke it up and applied it to the x and y values however. next step is figuring out how to tween the affect like you would find in tweenmax for flash. i believe its called interpolation in the android sdk